# Where is the mistake in this integral for get the correct cumulative distribution?

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Hi I am trying to calculate the upper cumulutative distribution for

x = 7.376 and v=15

For do this I am folowing the next steps:

Student's $t$-distribution $t(x,\nu)$

(1) probability density

$$f(x,\nu)={\frac{(1+\frac{x^2}{\nu})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{\nu}B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})}}$$

(2) lower cumulative distribution

$$P(x,\nu)={\int_{\small-\infty}^{\small x}}f(t,\nu)dt$$

(3) upper cumulative distribution

$$Q(x,\nu)={\int_{\small x}^{\small\infty}}f(t,\nu)dt$$

When I ramplace in 3, I get the following:

$${\int_{\small 7.376}^{\small\infty}}{\frac{(1+\frac{t^2}{15})^{-\frac{15+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{15}B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{15}{2})}}dt$$

When do I try to calculate with wolfram or another, not show the value and put that is a divergent integral, but when try to calculate, the upper cumulative distribution with another tool I can get the correct value ? 1.153280......

Where is the error in the integral, how can I calculate for get 1.153280....

THanks.

Comment: What does $B$ denote? The beta function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{15} B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{15}{2}\right)}\int \frac{dt}{\left(1+\frac{t^2}{15}\right)^8}$$

First, let $t=x \sqrt{15}$ to make 
$$I=\frac{1}{ B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{15}{2}\right)}\int \frac{dx}{\left(1+x^2\right)^8}$$

Use the reduction formula
$$\int \frac{dx}{\left(1+x^2\right)^n}=\frac{2n-3}{2(n-1)}\int \frac{dx}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n-1}}+\frac x{2(n-1)(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$$ to get
$$J=\int \frac{dx}{\left(1+x^2\right)^8}=\dfrac{429\arctan\left(x\right)}{2048}+$$ $$\dfrac{x\left(45045x^{12}+300300x^{10}+849849x^8+1317888x^6+1200199x^4+631540x^2+169995\right)}{215040\left(1+x^2\right)^7}$$

When $x\to \infty$, $J\to B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{15}{2}\right)=\frac{429 \pi }{2048}$ and we need to evaluate the expression for $x=\frac {7.376}{\sqrt{15}}=\frac{922}{125 \sqrt{15}}$

This gives by the end $I \sim 1.153280\times 10^{-6}$ as already given by @Jean-Claude Arbaut in comments.